# what are alternatives to SpringBatch Listners in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

In Spring, Is there something similar to SpringBatch listeners(ex: ItemReadListeners) to listen and log statements while processing the business logic in another class or method?

Say, I would like to add additional logging through listeners and dont want to write in the actual class. I have an inherited code with business logic and cant change/add to it. So planning to add something to do additional logging?

What is the best practice/guidance to achieve this in spring?

Answer (score 0):

Spring offers you the AOP module to solve this kind of problems (cross cutting concern).
Check around the net "how to log DAO/service modules calls" or "how to calculate method execution using Spring AOP".